# C# How to Access Hidden DataTable Columns That is DataSource Binded in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, hidden-field

I having a hard time trying to access hidden columns that been hidden in DataTable which later bind and accessed in DataGridView

In Details : dtResult is a DataTable
Example Tried :

```
dtResult.Columns[i].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
```

OR

```
dtResult.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
```

Then Store into DataSource of DataGridView :

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dtResult;
```

Accessing Hidden Columns occur error :  "Columns 'Active' Cannot be found" :

```
dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["active"].Value.ToString()
```

So Is there are way for **DataGridView** to **get Hidden Columns** that been **hidden** in **DataTable before binding it into DataGridView** ?

Please help me~ . Thank you

FYI :

```
I just realized
That DataSource Binding doesn't include Hidden Columns of DataTable.
Means That If DataTable.Column.Count = 10. (2 Hidden)
DataGridView.DataSource = DataTable.
DataGridView.Column.Count == 8.
```

So lead me to ask. 
How to Bind Those Hidden Column into the DataGridView From DataTable

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to hide the column in the datatable ? Visability in UI is a UI concern, I would bind the the datatable to the datagridview and hide the desired columns in the datagridview.

Comment: I agree fully with this. Ontop of what you said, once a column is hidden in a datagridview, it is still fully accessible by code and easy to manipulate/work with.  It's just not visible to the user.     dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["active"].Value.ToString()   ... Should work with no issues.

Comment: Yes Indeed, I totally agree with what you just said. It is just that the project was designed in All DataGridView is global usage and had DataTable as data source .
Had been stretching my brain to solve this puzzle. 
But anyway, thanks for answer. Thank XD I try to use other approach

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had the same issue today so I am posting my solution. I was using DataSet.ReadXml(Stream) to dump an xml file into a DataSet and the columns that are generated for relations were not showing up in a DataGridView. The following code loops through all of the columns in each DataTable in the DataSet and changes the ColumnMapping property to MappingType.Element. I picked MappingType.Element since the visible columns were set to that and the description fits for my situation: "The column is mapped to an XML element."

**Short answer:** Change the ColumnMapping from MappingType.Hidden to something that is not hidden before binding to the DataGridView.

```
    ...
    DataSet ds;
    ...
    foreach(DataTable dtbl in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn dcol in dtbl.Columns)
        {
            if (dcol.ColumnMapping == MappingType.Hidden)
            {
                dcol.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Element;
            }
        }
    }

    DataGridView.DataSource = ds;
```

Then if you need to hide them in UI you can do it on the DataGridView.